# How to add multiple marks on MapView - over a hundred

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-mapview

I followed the Hello MapView tutorial on the developer site, and got everything working well.  But now I need to expand upon that to add around 150 markers, and my current method crashes my app.

> Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut

My set up is as follows..

Four String arrays with the data for the map, all have (and always will) have the exact same number of indexes and fId[0] == fLatitude[0] == fLongitude[0] == fDetails[0], and so on:

```
    String[] fId;
    String[] fLatitude;
    String[] fLongitude;
    String[] fDetails;
```

As of now this is how I am plotting the points on the map.  This is obviously not the correct way because the map keeps crashing:

```
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
    FriendItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new FriendItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView.getContext());

    for(int i=0;i<aLatitude.length;i++){

        Double intLon = Double.parseDouble(aLongitude[i]);
        Double intLat = Double.parseDouble(aLatitude[i]);

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(intLat * 1E6), 
                (int)(intLon * 1E6));
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Friend ", "Something");

        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

    }
```

Let me know in the comments if you need anymore info, thanks.

Logcat:

> 01-13 18:39:34.732: ERROR/MapActivity(1085): Couldn't get connection factory client
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69): ANR in com.example.friendapp (com.example.friendapp/.FriendMaps)
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69): Load: 2.39 / 0.78 / 0.42
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69): CPU usage from 6026ms to 0ms ago:
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69):   93% 1085/com.example.friendapp: 93% user + 0% kernel / faults: 25 minor
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69):   2.6% 69/system_server: 1.8% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 3 minor
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69):   1.1% 875/com.google.process.gapps: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69):   1.1% 980/com.android.quicksearchbox: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69):   0.9% 133/com.android.launcher: 0% user + 0.9% kernel
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69):   0.1% 40/adbd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69): 100% TOTAL: 95% user + 4.1% kernel
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69): CPU usage from 2192ms to 2863ms later:
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69):   80% 1085/com.example.friendapp: 80% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3 minor
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69):     77% 1085/bile.friendapp: 77% user + 0% kernel
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69):   16% 69/system_server: 4.8% user + 11% kernel
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69):     14% 101/InputDispatcher: 3.2% user + 11% kernel
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69):     1.6% 70/HeapWorker: 1.6% user + 0% kernel
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69):   0.5% 133/com.android.launcher: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69):     0.5% 134/HeapWorker: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69):   0.6% 980/com.android.quicksearchbox: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69):     1.3% 981/HeapWorker: 0% user + 1.3% kernel
>   01-13 18:40:14.473: ERROR/ActivityManager(69): 100% TOTAL: 80% user + 19% kernel
>   01-13 18:40:20.702: ERROR/InputDispatcher(69): channel '406f88b8 com.example.friendapp/com.example.friendapp.FriendMaps (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
>   01-13 18:40:20.712: ERROR/InputDispatcher(69): channel '406f88b8 com.example.friendapp/com.example.friendapp.FriendMaps (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Comment: How is it crashing. What's your logcat say.

Comment: @Falmarri - Tag - ActivityManager - ANR in com.example.friends, then Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut...

Comment: Show more of your logcat. Edit your question and include all relevant stack trace.

Comment: @Falmarri - just getting used to logcat - thats all the output from the error view.  Do you need anything else?

Comment: re-think your map marker management, I had the same problem some month ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529022/map-marker-management-android I used a markermanager to link the markers with the resources (images) and it worked for me

Comment: @ArtWorkAD - I am grabbing all the data for the map from a text string from a webpage on my server.  So sucking that into arrays is pretty necessary for me - after I have the data in my arrays do you recommend anything?

Comment: I do pretty much the same, grabbing some json data from the web, actually shop information, and display this as markers on the map, it works for me with the way I described in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the same overlay 150 times to the map. Please only add it once.